# Get server URL from file input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, materialize

I need to manage some files who are uploaded to my server, but I need to get the URL of the selected file. I know you can't do this with javascript with files outside the server, but I wanna know if there's a way to get the URL from files in the server. For example I got this image from my file input with a selected file (LTAIPBCS75FI.xls) who is hosted in "xls/ITAI2016/Fraccion01/" in my home directory. I get this URL from php:

[URL IN FILE INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVvE1.png)

I need then to get the full directory when I select a file in my server.

Comment: You cannot get the actual full file path of a file supplied to an `<input>` file element.

Comment: Usually you should have record in DB file id, name and path. Then you manage the file using the id and server will know the path using the DB